# Oшибка 405 при попытке авторизации

Tags: python, парсер, python-3.5, requests

Пытаюсь авторизоваться на сайте и ничего не выходит. Получаю страницу с ошибкой

> 405 Not Allowed

Все токены скопировал из fiddler а так же напрямую из браузера - не помогло.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class bosslike(object):
    def auth_(self):
        session = requests.session()
        url = 'http://bosslike.ru/login/'
        params = {'UserLogin[login]': u'pu2ok54y.iap@20minutemail.it',
                  'UserLogin[password]': u'pu2ok54y.iap@20minutemail.it',
                  'submitLogin': u'Войти'}

        headers = {
        'Host': 'bosslike.ru',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0',
        'Set-Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=65168a6ed4ac12e3045b89571cc1c1be; path=/; HttpOnly',
        'CF-RAY': '42fc9c20768985e9-ARN',
        'Location': 'http://bosslike.ru/tasks/my/',
        'Referer': 'http://bosslike.ru/login/'
    }
        r = session.post(url,params,headers)
        print(r.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bosslike = bosslike()
    bosslike.auth_()
```

Comment: 1- посмотрите происходят ли перенаправления 2- исправьте вызов post(): как именованный параметр передавайте params. Если ошибка без headers воспроизводится, то уберите из вызова.

Answer (score 0):

405-я ошибка означает, что вы делаете запрос не того типа. Вероятно, сервер ждёт GET вместо POST.

Comment: он ждет пост, что можно увидить в отладчике

Comment: Значит что-то не так с сервером, 405-я возвращается только в случае [неправильного метода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#405).

Comment: а вы можете посмотреть что не так?)

Comment: Только если вы можете предоставить доступ к исходному коду бэкенда.

Comment: если бы я имел к нему доступ - я бы не писал парсер